# why it can be "bad file number" when i write to socket

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have a problem with sending message to server socket from client.
write function returns error - **bad file number**. It means that I haven't permission to write to this socket.
But from another client I can write to this socket, and do it successfully.
Most interesting, that when another client connected to server my(problem) client can send message too.

the code of my client:

```c
SOCKET OnceCommand;
struct sockaddr_in SAddress4;

struct autoC
{
  char buf[4];
  short fromx;
  short fromy;
  short tox;
  short toy;
  char step;
  char cycle;
};
union autocomm{
  char byte[14];
  struct autoC command;
} Command1, Command2;

memset(&SAddress4,0,sizeof(SAddress4));
SAddress4.sin_family = AF_INET;
SAddress4.sin_port = htons(444);
SAddress4.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(RobotsIP[Robot1]);
memset(&(SAddress4.sin_zero),0,8);

if((OnceCommand = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))!=SOCKET_ERROR)
{
  Err(OnceCommand);
  if(conn = connect(OnceCommand,(struct sockaddr *)&SAddress4,sizeof(struct sockaddr))!=SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    rc = write(OnceCommand,(char*)Command1.byte,sizeof(Command1.byte));
    if(rc < 0)
    {
      perror("Client-write() error");
      rc = getsockopt(OnceCommand, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &temp, &length);
      if(rc == 0)
      {
        Err(OnceCommand);
        perror("SO_ERROR was");
      }
      closesocket(OnceCommand);
    }
    else
    {
      adv_printf("Client-write() is OK\n");
      adv_printf("String successfully sent lol!\n");
    }
    shutdown(OnceCommand,2);
    closesocket(OnceCommand);
  }
}
```

in SO_ERROR was "bad file number"

I'm using sockets lib in ADAM-5510 microcontroller based with ROM-DOS.

I tried to solve this problem by using NONBLOCKing sockets, but select returns only read ready flag.

Comment: This may solve a different problem from the one you reported, but should `write(OnceCommand,(char*)Command1.byte,sizeof(Command1.byte));` take `&Command1.byte` as the 2nd parameter, which should be a pointer to the data you want to write?

Comment: Command1 - is a union with a structure and char massive named "byte". i think it has no difference in this case. But i checked, and it still returns my "bad file number" error : (

Comment: You should really tag this question more appropriately. It does not look like valid sockets code but some nonstandard variant like winsock... And that could make a big difference to how errors are reported and whether `perror` is even printing something meaningful...

Comment: If you get any error you are closing the socket. You are then unconditionally shutting it down and closing it. (The shutdown is redundant actually.) What was in SO_ERROR? And how is OnceCommand declared?

Comment: Can't agree with you about shutdown function. I think it's soft and safe socket disposal. Added socket and structure declarations.

Comment: @dubundu The shutdown will do nothing, or rather fail, if the socket is already closed, and if the socket isn't closed it will just send the same FIN that the following close would have sent anyway. It's redundant, when not erroneous. Are we to understand that the socket handle is a static variable? If so there's your roblem. Make it local to the method. Ditto all the address structures.

Comment: SOCKET variable, all structures and sockaddr_in structure are local. I cant understand, why when i connect another client to server THIS client sends too.

Comment: @dubundu That suggests that one or more of your assumptions is false.

Comment: Possibily unrelated, but your `connect` should be: `connect(OnceCommand,(struct sockaddr *)&SAddress4,sizeof SAddress4)`

Comment: @dubundu Your assumption that the variables are method-local and not static for a start.

Comment: Should i add function name and braces in shown code to convince you?

Comment: Does the `connect()` actually succeed?  Can you check your connect call against zero instead of SOCKET_ERROR to be sure.  (Note that your statement `if(conn = connect(...) != SOCKET_ERROR)` needs extra brackets around the assignment).

Comment: I know that connect is succeed because i have accept on server, and server after accept trying to receive data, but get it corrupted(i think its some trash in buffers)

Answer (score 0):

You are using 0 for the protocol. What is this supposed to be?  If TCP, try using IPPROTO_TCP in the socket call, ie.

```
OnceCommand = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
```

Comment: 0 sets by default protocol, which is IPPROTO_TCP

Comment: True, I just tried 0 on my own code and it works - I should have read the man page before answering :-(   BTW Is the error printed by the first `perror()` the same as the second and is the value in `temp` consistent with these?  I guess the call to getsockopt is just debug code. Or?  Also does `Err()` do anything significant?  Can you try a setsockopt() call before the write() to see if it works, eg `int opt = 1; if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &opt, (socklen_t) sizeof opt) < 0) perror("etc");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in client part of program. May be by the reason of using advantech socket library or another server program accepted clients' connect, but has no data to read. When i modified server program to receive data only by select it starts work fine.